# Dict showing as None when passed into function

Tags: python, json, pandas, dictionary

I have a function that does an API call and returns a record, which eventually will be converted into a data frame.

The two functions that handle the request are as follows:

```
def get_json(url, params={}):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(get_token())}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
    return r.json()


def retrieve_record(record=None, profile_ID=None, page_ID=None):
    profile_ID = str(profile_ID)
    pages_ID = str(page_ID)
    print_function_call("retrieve_record()", [profile_ID, pages_ID])
    return get_json(root_path + '/exzact/api/v60/profiles/{}/pages/{}/records/{}'.format(profile_ID, pages_ID, record))
```

Which returns an object that I then print to the console. The object is extremely long, but looks something like this:

```
{u'created_date': u'2017-10-24T17:41:15+00:00', ...}
```

There is clearly data inside the object. But when I then try and convert it into a data frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
obj = retrieve_record(profile_ID=profile_ID, page_ID=page_ID, record=ID)
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(obj, orient='index')
```

I'm getting this error in response:

```
Error: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Now I can assume that the error is happening inside the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()` function call. But I can't tell why. The dictionary I'm passing clearly has data inside of it, but it's being evaluated as `NoneType`.

I'm looking for suggestions on what could be going wrong with my dictionary object. Is it perhaps that some fields inside the dictionary are of `NoneType`, and not the whole object itself?

**TRACEBACK**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 456, in <module>
    newDF = create_DF(profile_ID, page_ID, today_ids)
  File "", line 211, in create_DF
    data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(obj, orient='index')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 861, in from_dict
    return cls(data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 314, in __init__
    arrays, columns = _to_arrays(data, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5715, in _to_arrays
    dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5792, in _list_to_arrays
    content = list(lib.to_object_array(data).T)
  File "pandas\_libs\src\inference.pyx", line 1614, in pandas._libs.lib.to_object_array (pandas\_libs\lib.c:66831)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

**Full Dictionary**

```
{u'company_sub_post_installation_clean_up': [], u'dcms_': u'890835', u'email_inspection': None, u'company_sub_welding': [], u'company_sub_joining_plastic': [], u'job_type': u'service', u'job_material_type': u'plastic', u'if_other_type_crew_leader_name': None, u'company_sub_safety': [{u'equipment_safety_functional': None, u'fire_extinguisher_being_used': u'meets', u'appropriate_ppe_was_used': u'meets', u'server_modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:41:15+00:00', u'id': 69, u'parent_element_id': 277320543, u'vehicletrailerequipment_cones_present': u'meets', u'modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:39:22+00:00', u'vehicletrailer_wheel_chocks_present': u'meets', u'modified_by': u'company', u'fire_extinguisher_date_acceptable': u'meets', u'chemicals_properly_labeled_hazcom': None, u'created_by': u'company', u'safety_comments__photos': [], u'modified_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'complete_trench_entry_form': None, u'created_location': u'35.625220:-80.467894:0.000000:24.400999:24.400999:0.000000:0.000000:1508866785280.000000', u'appropriate_traffic_control_was_used': u'meets', u'select_items_not_met': None, u'javascript_state': u'{}', u'fire_extinguisher_fully_charged': u'meets', u'gas_co_oxygen_detector_used': None, u'parent_record_id': 87, u'shoring_equipment_trench_box_operation': None, u'shoring_used': None, u'modified_location': u'35.625220:-80.467894:0.000000:24.400999:24.400999:0.000000:0.000000:1508866785280.000000', u'parent_page_id': 3440925, u'ladder_operation_acceptable': None, u'ladder_used': None, u'created_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'equipment_safety_being_used': None, u'select_trafic_items_not_met': None, u'equipmenttools_proper_distance_from_trench': None, u'created_date': u'2017-10-24T17:39:22+00:00', u'prejob_brief_was_performed_and_documented': u'meets'}], u'server_modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:41:14+00:00', u'id': 87, u'parent_element_id': 0, u'date1': u'2017-10-24', u'modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:41:06+00:00', u'company_sub_trench': [{u'modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:39:32+00:00', u'javascript_state': u'{}', u'parent_page_id': 3440925, u'no_weak_link_issues': None, u'oq_present_texca001_inspection_of_excavation_activities': u'meets', u'server_modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:41:16+00:00', u'created_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'parent_record_id': 87, u'depth_consistent_along_trenchline': None, u'created_by': u'company', u'trench_photos__comments': [], u'trench_depth_adequate': None, u'modified_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'trench_width_adequate': None, u'created_date': u'2017-10-24T17:39:32+00:00', u'modified_by': u'company', u'created_location': u'35.625220:-80.467894:0.000000:24.812000:24.812000:0.000000:0.000000:1508866785280.000000', u'modified_location': u'35.625220:-80.467894:0.000000:24.812000:24.812000:0.000000:0.000000:1508866785280.000000', u'id': 48, u'parent_element_id': 277320810, u'proper_dewatering': None}], u'modified_by': u'company', u'job_materials_photos__comments': [], u'created_by': u'company', u'catalogue_number': None, u'company_sub_pressure_test': [], u'company_sub_working_around_utilities': [], u'modified_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'crew_leader': u'kenneth_black__n18031', u'company_sub__purging__abandon': [], u'title__address': u'464 Sonoma dr', u'damaged_material_repaired_or_removed': None, u'company_sub_equipment_and_tools': [], u'type_of_nonconformance': None, u'company_sub_tie_ins': [], u'pipe_within_allowable_date_range': u'meets', u'pipe_materials_properly_marked': u'meets', u'javascript_state': u'null', u'responsible_for_nonconformance': None, u'company_sub_job_documentation': [], u'company_sub_design_adherance': [], u'company_sub_backfilling': [], u'parent_record_id': 0, u'job_sub_type': u'residential', u'my_element4': u'', u'company_sub_pigging': [], u'company_sub_coating': [], u'company_sub_cathodic_protection': [], u'company_sub_bore': [{u'proper_depth': u'meets', u'bore_photos__comments': [], u'visual_inspection_of_pipe_during_pullback': None, u'environmental_standards__protections_observered': None, u'server_modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:41:17+00:00', u'id': 18, u'parent_element_id': 277320816, u'modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:39:48+00:00', u'modified_by': u'company', u'no_head_size_problems_size_of_reamer_appropriate': None, u'created_by': u'company', u'modified_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'created_location': u'35.624811:-80.468068:0.000000:27.521999:27.521999:0.000000:0.000000:1508866785280.000000', u'type_of_bore': None, u'no_weak_link_issues': None, u'javascript_state': u'{}', u'bore_profile_present': None, u'parent_record_id': 87, u'modified_location': u'35.624811:-80.468068:0.000000:27.521999:27.521999:0.000000:0.000000:1508866785280.000000', u'parent_page_id': 3440925, u'created_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'permitting_adequate': None, u'tracer_wire_present': None, u'created_date': u'2017-10-24T17:39:48+00:00'}], u'modified_location': u'35.625220:-80.467894:0.000000:25.257000:25.257000:0.000000:0.000000:1508866785280.000000', u'created_location': u'35.624811:-80.468068:0.000000:22.379999:22.379999:0.000000:0.000000:1508866654208.000000', u'company_inspected': u'mears_construction', u'project_ir_': u'08003', u'parent_page_id': 0, u'created_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'asset_information_multiple': [{u'date_a1_value': u'', u'picture_of_asset': None, u'data_value': u'', u'd_value': u'0', u'data_result': u'', u'lot_code_code': None, u'size_code': None, u'material_type': u'plastic_pipe', u'a4_lotcode': u'', u'lot_code': u'0', u'a1v': u'', u'a2_lotcode_code': None, u'c2_final_value': u'', u'c2': None, u'date_a3_code': u'', u'c1_final': u'', u'production_date_leap_year': u', 200', u'server_modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:41:15+00:00', u'id': 51, u'parent_element_id': 277320738, u'a3v': u'', u'modified_date': u'2017-10-24T17:38:41+00:00', u'modified_by': u'company', u'a2_lotcode': u'', u'production_date': u', 200', u'dayly_final': u'', u'picture_of_nonconformance': None, u'a1_lotcode': u'', u'data_result_split': u' ', u'c1_final_value': u'', u'created_by': u'company', u'a3_lotcode': u'', u'date_code': None, u'modified_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'lotcodesplit': u'', u'date_a1_code': None, u'created_location': u'35.624811:-80.468068:0.000000:22.379999:22.379999:0.000000:0.000000:1508866654208.000000', u'leap_year': u'0', u'type_of_nonconformance': None, u'a3_lotcode_code': None, u'a4_lotcode_code': u'', u'component_type_code': None, u'javascript_state': u'{}', u'size_split': u'', u'responsible_for_nonconformance': None, u'a2v': u'', u'c2_final': u'', u'material': u'', u'parent_record_id': 87, u'year1': u'200', u'a1': None, u'barcode_on_fitting__pipe': None, u'a2': None, u'date_a3_value': u'', u'a1_lotcode_code': None, u'manufacturer_code': u' ', u'modified_location': u'35.624811:-80.468068:0.000000:22.379999:22.379999:0.000000:0.000000:1508866654208.000000', u'catalogue_number': None, u'date_d_value_split': u'||0', u'date_a2_value': u'', u'day_final': u'', u'parent_page_id': 3440925, u'd': u'0', u'component_type': u'', u'day_ly_raw': u'', u'created_device_id': u'990006001231835', u'a3': u'', u'date_code_split': u'', u'material_code': None, u'day_raw': u'', u'manufacturer': u'', u'created_date': u'2017-10-24T17:38:40+00:00', u'date_a2_code': None, u'nonconformance_': u'No', u'display': None}], u'matieral_condition': u'meets', u'company_sub_material_handling': [], u'company_sub_manuals': [], u'created_date': u'2017-10-24T17:38:25+00:00', u'inspector_id': u'company', u'inspection_overall_comments_and_photos': [], u'company_sub_environmental': []}
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman updated.

Comment: @PRMoureu can you expanded on that? This code is being reused from a previous employee who was familiar with the pandas library. Since I'm not familiar myself it's making the problem a bit harder to fix.

Comment: could you show a bigger sample of the dictionary ?

Comment: @PRMoureu Yes, give me one second.

Comment: `d = {'one':[100,10], 'two': None}
` this dictionary will throw the same error, i cannot say it's the same cause, but maybe a lead...

Comment: @PRMoureu added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here:

The issue was not that the dictionary itself was `None`, but that it held values of `None` type. The reason why this went unnoticed is because our previous use of the script required all the fields in the record to be filled out.

Whereas this time around a lot of the record fields are optional to fill out. The `None` key/value pairs will have to be removed from the dictionary before converting them into a `DataFrame`. Once they are removed, the error will no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

But clearly the dictionary key eg.: u'company_sub_post_installation_clean_up' and the correspnding value seems invalid in the first place so i guess those should be sorted out so it wouldn't result any None- entries. But good if your workaround fixes the issues!

Comment: I think part of the confusion came from the fact that some of the keys have values that are deep objects (sub forms of the record). My thought was that I would have to flatten the object before I could print it out. It took me too long to realize that they were actually just empty. I appreciate your help nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe returning r.json().decode('utf-8') would help on this?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: r.decode('utf-8').json()? This is just guessing but seems that get() returns the encoded data...

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'decode'`. Not sure what's going on here. I'll keep playing around with the response

Comment: printing `r.encoding` returns `None`. But that doesn't make sense because clearly the `u\`` character is seen in the dictionary

Comment: you could iterate all the entries in 'r' and apply .encode('utf-8') to all of them before returning

Comment: Do you think that the encoding is what could be causing the issue? What kind of performance hit would I take for looping through all that data. I provided one example in my question, but there could possibly be hundreds of records to go through

Comment: Yes it might be the issue. It could be that accessing 'r' will return the content as unicode format as a default. So can you try to print r.text() after setting r.encoding='utf-8'? C.f. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v1.2.3/user/quickstart/#response-content